# Report Builder 3.0 unable to access SharePoint Foundation 2010 Report Server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I am having a terrrible time getting this to work. I have configured the SharePoint site and the SQL Servers involved to use Kerberos. That has been confirmed working.

I then configured the SharePoint site's Reporting Services integration (trusted account), enabled anonymous access and enabled report builder. I can launch report builder without any issues at all. The problem comes when I try to save my report. When Report Builder is started Items->New-ReportBuilder Report it opens and display in the lower left hand corner "No current report server." When I close the Wizard dialog and click connect I enter http://server.fqdn.net and I receive the following error:

> Connection failed:
>
> Unable to connect to the server that
>   is specified in the URL,
>   'http://servername.fqdn.net/'.
>
> Make sure that the server is running,
>   the URL is correct, and you have
>   permission to use the server.

I have also tried http://servername.fqdn.net/reportsserver/. When I try that I receive a login prompt. When I enter my credentials it tries for a few seconds and then sends another login prompt. I installed the report server using default settings. The reporting services db is on the same server as sharepoint. The configuration and other databases are on a remote SQL Server. I am able to browse the http://servername.fqdn.net/reportsserver/ URL and see the directory structure in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The initial installation must have been bad because it would not let us download report builder.
2. We turned on anonymous access based on a few articles we found online. This allowed us to download report builder.
3. Report builder was unable to access the report server. This was the issue.
4. I reinstalled but continued to enable anonymous access assuming it was required, even though I had not done it on the initial test deployment (which did work).
5. I continued to get the error that the report server did not exist.
6. I reinstalled again and tried another fix.
7. I reinstalled a third time but did not enable anonymous access, because that was the only thing I could think that was different between the test site that worked and this one.

Self inflicted wounds.... Ugh.

Comment: There seems to be an element of the AAMs causing problems too.